# Filter R Data Frame by SQL Column Names

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, dataframe

I am currently attempting to view only part of a sql query (which I believe I have made into a data frame). However, it doesn't seem to work properly and when I go to view the supposedly-filtered data, it is not filtering as I expected. Below is a redacted version of my code. My query is correct as I have successfully used it for other items. However, I am not sure how to only view information from one column name in order to do additional calculations on that data.

```
overall <- dbSendQuery(con1, glue_sql("SELECT [REDACTED COL NAME], [REDACTED COL NAME2] FROM [REDACTED TABLE NAME]..."))
overall % > %
     select(REDACTED COL NAME)
```

Comment: Did you get an error or something when you tried to run the above code? If so, what exactly was the error message. Do you have `dplyr` loaded for the `select()` function? And note that it's `%>%` without spaces -- with spaces will not work (that's technically a different function name)

Comment: I'm getting the error: no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of a class "c('OdbcResult', 'DBIResult', 'DBIObject')". I have both the dplyr package installed and loaded

Comment: If you use `dbSendQuery` then you need to fetch the results. Maybe try `dbSendQuery(...) %>% dbFetch() %>% select(...)`

Comment: Ok thanks! It isn't giving me an error now but how do I go about using that select statement for calculations, etc.?

Comment: For example, if I wanted to calculate the sum of that select(column). How would I write that?

Comment: You should probably consult a basic introduction to `dplyr` if that's the direction you want do go. Look into the `summarize()` verb,

Comment: If you're not planning on doing anything with the prepared statement, instead of `dbSendQuery` and `dbFetch`, the canonical preference is to *just* use `dbGetQuery(con, somequery)` to retrieve the results in one function call.

Comment: `bhon123`, I understand and appreciate the need to redact your real query for proprietary information. However, it's also good to still provide *usable code*, as it can be frustrating trying to parse through obvious syntax errors as typos. For instance, `overall % > %` should fail with `unexpected input`, whereas I'm assuming you mean `overall %>%` (no spaces between the `%` and `>` symbols). While it seems obvious here, please get into the practice of providing usable code in your questions, it can really help. Thanks!